# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql

I created password using `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'newPassword'` in postgresql.  I am still getting the same error in amazon ubuntu server. Can any one provide solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:-

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'newPassword';
```